# BASH - SED insert new line before last, containing tab and variable

Tags: bash, sed

I'm trying to insert a new line into a file just before the last line. The new line includes `tab` and a variable.

Using the following.  This inserts the line at the correct place, includes the tab but doesn't expand the variable.

```
sed '$i \\tnewline = $newvalue' file
```

If I wrap it in double quotes instead of single quotes I get errors.
`sed: -e expression #1, char 13: unterminated address regex`

How do I do this ?

Thanks

Comment: Hi, I've tried that and it generates the error I've posted.

Comment: please update the question with a sample input file, the output from `typeset -p newvalue` and the (correct) expected output

Comment: It is not about difference in single and double quotes as OP has already tried double quotes. As per OP: `If I wrap it in double quotes instead of single quotes I get errors. sed: -e expression #1, char 13: unterminated address regex`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this `sed`:

```sh
sed "\$i \\\\tnewline = $newvalue" file
```

Difference is escaping first `$` when we use double quotes and use of `\\\\t` instead of `\\t` due to expansion of double quotes in shell.

Comment: Perfect thanks for explaining why the additional slashes are needed.